# Eclipse ODS Indexer Can't Find right include .h file, but refer to an outside-project's reference .h include

Tags: c++, eclipse, indexing, include, ods

Problematic:

Big C++ project code, with many relative references of ouside project.
Using Eclipse ODS's indexing.

Problem happens when I make a non-slight changes in a header's file(add new functions, new member data of class)
then i used them in my cpp code, but after it, even i re-build in Indexer, Indexer can not refer anymore to right Include header, specially, all my newly added variable or function becomes unsolved. and all other func in that header can not be refered to this include in project, but indexer search another original include from outside references.

i have tried:
 re-config project, rebuild refresh in Indexer. 
or close proejct-- re-open it,
delete this eclipse project and create new one with the same codes.
etc...

But all fail to index to right include header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solve the problem.

We need to modify in this:
in Properties of project --C/C++ General -- Paths and symbols --- Includes ---there are three in option of Language( I change each in them though).

I delete the duplicated exterier's .h file in the list, and manuelly add the path of the right include of the project in it.

then re- indexer it.( or againe close eclipse,re-open)

After it, it can refer rightly to the header.

Done!